# blank page on navigation

Tags: android, mobile, cordova, qooxdoo

On certain android devices my mobile app built using phonegap and using qooxdoo 3.0.1 shows a blank page with only the header on back navigation. I see the same behavior on using the mobile demo site as well, has anyone come across a similar issue.

**EDIT** - Updated to qooxdoo 3.5, issue persists there as well. 
`Android Version - 4.2.2`, works samsung galaxy grande but fails on xolo a500s

Comment: I use the 3.0.x branch from github since some weeks and I have not notices such an issue. Yesterday the core team released 3.0.2, does an update fix your issue?

Comment: could you be a bit more precise about the issue? What android devices and what OS version did you use? Is there a way to reproduce the issue with the online demos?

Comment: @Christian - recently updated to 3.5 and see the behavior there as well. This is specific to some devices, works on other devices with the same android version(not sure if manufacturer specific skin can be an issue here)

Comment: @Martin - android version is 4.2.2 and i am able to see the behavior when i browse to the demo on the website from the default android browser but works fine if i use it from chrome on the same device. The device i use is a low end one from a manufacturer called Xolo (a500s)

Comment: This might be an issue with the rendering of iScroll and the weak GPU. Have you tried the developer demo version?  http://demo.qooxdoo.org/devel/mobileshowcase/index.html#%2F

Comment: Tried the showcase demo on the default browser and i see the same issue. If i try it from chrome on the same device it works fine